# WPF intput binding interrupted

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have something like the following XAML code:

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.InputBindings>
        <!-- Command implemented in the view model -->
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding RemoveLastTextBox}" Key="R" Modifiers="Ctrl"/>
    </UserControl.InputBindings>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfNames}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

</UserControl>
```

So, every time I press Ctrl-R the last `TextBox` is removed from the stack. However, when a `TextBox` with the keyboard focus is removed, the entire `UserControl` loses focus and Ctrl-R key doesn't work anymore.

I tried setting `Focusable` and `FocusManager.IsFocusScope` on the `UserControl`, but that didn't help. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Try setting `<UserControl Focusable="True" x:Name="usrCtrl" ...>` and in `RemoveLastTextBox` at the end of the method use `usrCtrl.Focus()`

Comment: The `RemoveLastTextBox` is a relay command implemented in the view model and therefor UI elements are not accessible in the command's execute method. The list of TextBoxes is a reflection of an `ObservableCollection` in the view model and by removing elements from that collection the UI is updated (see updated post)

Comment: Then define event in viewmodel, like `public event Action TextBoxRemoved;`, subscribe to it in code behind (xaml.cs file) with: `viewModel.TextBoxRemoved += () => usrCtrl.Focus();`

Comment: Thanks. I used `CollectionChanged` event from `ObservableCollection` to refocus the `UserControl`. I think it's still a bit "hacky", but it does the job.

Comment: This is not normal. Can please show how you remove the text boxes? Where do you use the UserControl?